# How to calculate spread on gambling odds?

Tags: statistics, gambling

I'm trying to calculate the spread on a bet.

People are telling me it's either 10% (absolute) or 17% (relative).

I'm failing to see how to get either number. Bet is below:

---

Context: Which stock will end up more (%-wise) by the end of 2019. The options are either to buy Stock A at 6:5 or to buy Stock B at 2:1 (against)

I see 6:5 on Stock A side payout, which means if you bet on Stock A you get 1.2 rewards, if you bet on Stock B you get 0.83 rewards

I see lay 2:1 on Stock B, so if you bet on Stock B you get 0.5 rewards, if you bet on Stock A you get 2.0 rewards

Comment: This isn't even remotely clear.  "spread" would usually suggest some sort of bid-ask, but nothing like that is present.  What exactly do you mean by spread in this context?  And what does it mean to, say, buy Stock $A$ at $6:5$?

Comment: Your odds are 6:5 payout if you take the Stock A side. (Implying Bookie gets 5:6 odds on Stock B).


Your odds are 1:2 payout if you take the Stock B side. (Implying Bookie gets 2:1 odds on Stock A).

Comment: Odds of what?  A stock price is, effectively, a continuous process.  Are you placing a bet on some event or something like that?

Comment: Yes, the overall bet is: which stock will end up more (%-wise) by the end of 2019.

Comment: Ok.  So, $6:5$ odds means that $A$ is projected to win the race with probability $\frac 6{11}$.  I don't understand how you are quoting the bet on $B$, but whatever it is you intend you can easily translate into a probability.  I'd guess that whatever you meant by spread is a simple function of the fact that the sum of the two implied probabilities is less than $1$.